# Convert project from 2008 to 2010 from shell

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to convert Visual Studio project from 2008 to 2010 from shell? I need to make it during continious integration process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just `devenv.exe /upgrade [solutionfile.sln]` or `devenv.exe /upgrade [projectfile.vcproj]` for projects rather than solutions.

And just saw, apparently there's a new tool in 2010 called vcupgrade.exe that can also be used. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/25/to-the-command-line-enthusiasts-some-quick-know-hows-for-upgrading-to-vs-2010.aspx) blog post for details about both ways.

Comment: Thank you! /upgrade is what i was searching for (whether vcupgrade is C++ specific)

Comment: Is devenv.exe for the express version too?